# Scrapy Crawl only first 5 pages of the site

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on the solution to the following problem, My boss wants from me to create a `CrawlSpider` in `Scrapy` to scrape the article details like `title`, `description` and paginate only the first 5 pages.

I created a `CrawlSpider` but it is paginating from all the pages, How can I restrict the `CrawlSpider` to paginate only the first latest 5 pages?

The site article listing page markup that opens when we click on pagination next link:

**Listing page markup**:

```html
    <div class="list">
      <div class="snippet-content">
        <h2>
          <a href="https://example.com/article-1">Article 1</a>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="snippet-content">
        <h2>
          <a href="https://example.com/article-2">Article 2</a>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="snippet-content">
        <h2>
          <a href="https://example.com/article-3">Article 3</a>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="snippet-content">
        <h2>
          <a href="https://example.com/article-4">Article 4</a>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="next">
        <a href="https://www.example.com?page=2&keywords=&from=&topic=&year=&type="> Next </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

For this, I am using `Rule` object with `restrict_xpaths` argument to get all the article links, and for the follow I am executing `parse_item` class method that will get the article `title` and `description` from the `meta` tags.

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[contains(@class, "snippet-content")]/h2/a'), callback="parse_item",
             follow=True)
```

**Detail page markup**:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Article Title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.">
```

After this, I have added another `Rule` object to handle pagination `CrawlSpider` will use the following link to open other listing page and do the same procedure again and again.

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//ul[@class="pagination"]/li[@class="next"]/a'))
```

This is my `CrawlSpider` code:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import w3lib.html


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/"]
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'articles.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json'
    }
    total = 0

   
    rules = (
        # Get the list of all articles on the one page and follow these links
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[contains(@class, "snippet-content")]/h2/a'), callback="parse_item",
             follow=True),
        # After that get pagination next link get href and follow it, repeat the cycle
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//ul[@class="pagination"]/li[@class="next"]/a'))
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.total = self.total + 1
        title = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content').get() or ""
        description = w3lib.html.remove_tags(response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]/@content').get()) or ""
       
        return {
            'id': self.total,
            'title': title,
            'description': description
        }
```

Is there a way we can restrict the crawler to crawl only the first 5 pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** use [process_request](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules).

```py
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


def limit_requests(request, response):
    # here we have the page number.
    # page_number = request.url[-1]
    # if int(page_number) >= 6:
    #     return None

    # here we use a counter
    if not hasattr(limit_requests, "page_number"):
        limit_requests.page_number = 0
    limit_requests.page_number += 1

    if limit_requests.page_number >= 5:
        return None

    return request


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example_spider'

    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/']
    page = 0
    rules = (
        # Get the list of all articles on the one page and follow these links
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="card-body"]/h4/a'), callback="parse_item",
             follow=True),
        # After that get pagination next link get href and follow it, repeat the cycle
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="page-item"][last()]/a'), process_request=limit_requests)
    )
    total = 0

    def parse_item(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//h3//text()').get(default='')
        price = response.xpath('//div[@class="card-body"]/h4//text()').get(default='')
        self.total = self.total + 1

        return {
            'id': self.total,
            'title': title,
            'price': price
        }
```

**Solution 2:** overwrite `_requests_to_follow` method (should be slower though).

```py
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example_spider'

    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/']

    rules = (
        # Get the list of all articles on the one page and follow these links
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="card-body"]/h4/a'), callback="parse_item",
             follow=True),
        # After that get pagination next link get href and follow it, repeat the cycle
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="page-item"][last()]/a'))
    )
    total = 0
    page = 0
    
    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if not isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
            return
        if self.page >= 5:  # stopping condition
            return
        seen = set()
        for rule_index, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            links = [
                lnk
                for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response)
                if lnk not in seen
            ]
            for link in rule.process_links(links):
                if rule_index == 1: # assuming there's only one "next button"
                    self.page += 1
                seen.add(link)
                request = self._build_request(rule_index, link)
                yield rule.process_request(request, response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//h3//text()').get(default='')
        price = response.xpath('//div[@class="card-body"]/h4//text()').get(default='')
        self.total = self.total + 1

        return {
            'id': self.total,
            'title': title,
            'price': price
        }
```

The solutions are pretty much self explanatory, if you want me to add something please ask in the comments.

Comment: thanks for the answer, how we can pass the page counter inside the `limit_requests` function because the URL does not have a page no and each page list has10 links?

Comment: @VenNilson we can use a counter inside the function. See the edit to `solution 1`.